# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu) digitalocean vps django, nginx and gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean, ubuntu-18.04

I put up a site in production a week ago made using django and postgres on digitalocean and followed the django nginx, gunicorn and postgres tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04#configure-nginx-to-proxy-pass-to-gunicorn) and used digitalspace for our static file. everything was running smoothly and okay for the whole week while we were testing the website in production (left Debug=true for testing reasons). suddenly a few hours ago after i was testing some stuff i got a 502 bad gateway error. i checked the nginx error logs and heres the error:

> 2019/12/23 00:30:00 [error] 7988#7988: *2202 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 125.0.0.1, server: www.myapp.com, request: "GET /reviews/business/id=3/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/reviews/business/id=3/", host: "myapp.com", referrer: "https://myapp.com/category/Salon/"
>   2019/12/23 00:30:12 [error] 7988#7988: *2208 connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 125.0.0.1, server: www.myapp.com, request: "GET /reviews/business/id=3/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/reviews/business/id=3/", host: "myapp.com", referrer: "https://plentypot.biz/category/Salon/"
>   2019/12/23 00:30:25 [error] 7988#7988: *2212 connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 125.0.0.1, server: www.myapp.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/", host: "myapp.com"

i ran nginx -t and it returned successful meaning everything is okay with the configurations

the gunicorn error logs by using the command journalctl -u gunicorn, which outputed:

```
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]: [2019-12-16 13:00:49 +0000] [10979] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]: [2019-12-16 13:00:49 +0000] [10979] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/run/gunicorn
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]: [2019-12-16 13:00:49 +0000] [10979] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]: [2019-12-16 13:00:49 +0000] [10997] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10997
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]: [2019-12-16 13:00:49 +0000] [10997] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:   File "/home/cybafrican/djangoprojectdir/mydjangoenv/lib/python3.7/site-pa
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:     worker.init_process()
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:   File "/home/cybafrican/djangoprojectdir/mydjangoenv/lib/python3.7/site-pa
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:     self.load_wsgi()
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:   File "/home/cybafrican/djangoprojectdir/mydjangoenv/lib/python3.7/site-pa
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:   File "/home/cybafrican/djangoprojectdir/mydjangoenv/lib/python3.7/site-pa
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:     self.callable = self.load()
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:   File "/home/cybafrican/djangoprojectdir/mydjangoenv/lib/python3.7/site-pa
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:   File "/home/cybafrican/djangoprojectdir/mydjangoenv/lib/python3.7/site-pa
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:   File "/home/cybafrican/djangoprojectdir/mydjangoenv/lib/python3.7/site-pa
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:   File "/home/cybafrican/djangoprojectdir/mydjangoenv/lib/python3.7/importl
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocke
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp.wsgi'
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]: [2019-12-16 13:00:49 +0000] [10997] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10997)
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]: [2019-12-16 13:00:49 +0000] [11000] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11000
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]: [2019-12-16 13:00:49 +0000] [11000] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:   File "/home/cybafrican/djangoprojectdir/mydjangoenv/lib/python3.7/site-pa
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:     worker.init_process()
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:   File "/home/cybafrican/djangoprojectdir/mydjangoenv/lib/python3.7/site-pa
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:     self.load_wsgi()
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:   File "/home/cybafrican/djangoprojectdir/mydjangoenv/lib/python3.7/site-pa
Dec 16 13:00:49 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[10979]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
```

my gunicron configuration file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=cybafrican
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/cybafrican/djangoprojectdir
ExecStart=/home/cybafrican/djangoprojectdir/mydjangoenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
         myapp.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

my project path /home/cybafrican/djangoprojectdir:

```
└── djangoprojectdir
    ├── Pages
    ├── Recommend
    ├── Responses
    ├── Templates
    ├── Users
    ├── media
    ├── mydjangoenv
    ├── myapp
    ├── profiles
    └── static
```

i have went through everything online but cant seem to find any help with regards to this
Thank you

Comment: gunicorn cannot find your wsgi file "plentypot.wsgi". Does the file exist?

Comment: @IainShelvington yes it exists,i haven't deleted anything or modified any settings and its the first time i ran into something like this. i ran the status gunicorn socket command and received the following: gunicorn.socket - gunicorn socket
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: service-start-limit-hit) since Mon 2019-12-23 02:49:18 UTC; 51min ago
   Listen: /run/gunicorn.sock (Stream)

Comment: Can you share your gunicorn config and relevant parts of your directory structure?

Comment: gunicorn is complaining that it can't find "plentypot.wsgi" but you have "myapp.wsgi" in your config. Very strange

Comment: You may have to run `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl restart gunicorn` if you have made changes

Comment: apologies i have edited the actual name of the app to "myapp" in all occurences for privacy reasons that i cant get into, i just forgot to edit that part

Comment: You may have to add your directory to the python path http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#pythonpath

Comment: i have restored my droplet to a previous back up that was made and managed to get everything working again, thank you for all the help